# How to send email with more than one attachments in classic ASP?

Tags: email, asp-classic, attachment

how to attach more then one files and then send mail
using ASP Technology..

Not with ASP.NET

so please guide me..

and I want to send this mail when page load... so where should I write...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send email with classic ASP you can either use a third party control or use CDOSYS which comes with IIS.

Have a look at this page which gives you a good introduction to CDOSYS...
[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp)